# SQL: Filter on one column, then select max timestamp for results

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, hana

```
String stmt1 = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE created=(SELECT MAX(created)";
String stmt2 = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE source=somesource";
```

I'd like to combine these two statements. I have three sources, and I'd like the last created instance for each source (using three seperate queries).

Is there a way to select all elements from a source and THEN get the most recent timestamp?

Thank you.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your query attempt.

Comment: I'm using HANA and JDBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to do this using ANSI SQL is `row_number()` (which is supported by almost all databases including Hana):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY source ORDER BY created DESC) as seqnum
      FROM mytable t
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP BY in mysql to group some column with WHERE condition for example :

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
GROUP BY column_name(s)
```

In your case :

```
SELECT MAX(created)as date,* FROM mytable WHERE source=somesource GROUP   BY created;
```